# retrieve records by ascending order with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get the largest of 3 amount fields from my table. But there are 2 amount fields in the Transaction table named `expense_amt and income_amt`. I need to get the largest of 3 amount fields by looking on both fields. I understand that I can query with multiple fields like

```
Model.order('expense_amt', 'income_amt').limit(3)
```

But this does not return largest of 3 amount fields as i expected. So basically i need to retrieve largest of 3 transactions.
it would be like

```
Transactions
id    expense_amt   income_amt    transaction_type
1     100           NULL           1
2     200           NULL           3
3     NULL          400            1
4     NULL          800            2
5     1000          NULL           1

So the output of largest 3 would be [1000, 800, 400]
```

Comment: Based on your example - if there's a value for `expense_amt` then there woun't be a corresponding value for `income_amt`?

Comment: @Magnuss: No.. there wouldn't be. it is based on some condition that the form is getting saved. So ideally the db fields and values would look like this.. I just need to extract largest 3 amount fields

Answer (score 1):

This is not the prettiest solution, but maybe you can go somewhere from here :)

If the values cannot coincide, then the sum will always be the highest value. Using `COALESCE` SQL function, we replace `NULL` with `0` for the calculation to work.

```
Model.select("(COALESCE(expense_amt, 0) + COALESCE(income_amt, 0)) AS combined_amt").
  order("combined_amt DESC").
  limit(3).
  map{|row| row["combined_amt"]}
```

Comment: :- My intention is not to display the sum of 3 largest amount. I just need to display the largest 3 amounts records individually

Comment: @rubyist  - And it will. I'm not summing largest amounts. This code will display `[1000, 800, 400]`, since the calculation is as follows: `[1000 + 0, 0 + 800, 0 + 400]`

Comment: :- That worked. And I was trying to customize the query. Because I need other fields of the table and not just the row["combined_amt"].. So in the select statment i included other fields, but it seems to be not working. So Ideally i need id, transaction_type fields also in the result along with the combined_amt

Comment: This should be working fine with other statements in `select` clause, what exactly is the error?

Comment: I was thinking to get distinct records from it because my table will have records with same amount either in expense field or income field. So I just need to take the latest record only incase of same amount scenario. I tried like Model.select(" DISTINCT ON((COALESCE(expense_amt, 0) + COALESCE(income_amt, 0))) AS combined_amt").
  order("combined_amt DESC").
  limit(3).
  map{|row| row["combined_amt"]}. But it dint work. Am I missing something here. Basically I need to retreive records without duplicate amount fields

Comment: You can append `group("combined_amt").` As in: `Model.select(" .... AS combined_amt").group("combined_amt").order("combined_amt DESC")...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91506/discussion-between-rubyist-and-magnuss).

Answer (score 0):

I have edit this solution

```
    expense= Model.order('expense_amt DESC').limit(3).map{|exp| exp.expense_amt}
    income = Model.order('income_amt DESC').limit(3).map{|inc| inc.income_amt}
   result= expense +income
   result.sort{|a,b| b <=> a}.first(3)
```

Comment: This would return only records which has records of expense_amt with descending order. There can be records where expense_amt will be null or income_amt will be null. So I need to look both fields and then select 3 largest amounts

Comment: I have update this method,perhaps it should work according to you